# Get Class representing the class that declares a field

Tags: java, reflection

If I'm only given a field instance from a class, without further knowledge about the class that declares that field, is it possible to get an instance of the declaring (outer) class?

For instance, consider the following class structure.

```
class A {
    static final Tclass t = Tclass.create();
}
```

Now, in some other function, we are only given t (Tclass instance). Is it possible to use reflection in some way to grab the outer/declaring class (class A) that holds t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the statement *given t* means what you think it means.

If you mean you do something like

```
someMethod(t);
```

and you want `someMethod` to get a reference back to `A`, you're out of luck. When used in an expression like that, the expression `t` resolves to a value. That value is a reference to an object. Such a reference is *one-way* only. `someMethod` has absolutely no knowledge about the existence of a `static` variable `t`.

If you mean you have a `Field` instance for `t`, you can simply call `Field#getDeclaringClass()` to get the declaring class.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. What I was hoping was that the t instance somehow retained info about its containing class. Guess not.